# How to import AutoCAD .dwg files as overlay on map in Drupal (using OpenLayers)

Tags: overlay, autocad, dwg, drupal

I am using OpenLayers on my Drupal site. The request is to import AutoCAD .dwg files as an overlay to maps on the site. Is this possible and how? I found the [OpenLayers Editor for Drupal](https://drupal.org/project/ole), am I on the right path?

If this is possible by converting the .dwg file to another format, it would be an acceptable solution, too.

Comment: maybe http://mapguide.osgeo.org/ is a solution, i believe they suppord dwg somehow.

Comment: Okay, that's a start.Thank you. 
Do you think it's possible to implement with Drupal?